# Network and Sharing Center hung in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I'm having an issue wherein when I open the `Network and Sharing Center` in Windows 8.1, it hangs every time indefinitely.  The spinning wheel of death (busy cursor) is present on this window, but other applications seem to be okay, including other `Explorer` windows.

[image: Network and Sharing Center Hanging]

I have to think that there is something going on with the networking generally because I am seeing issues with some other applications that seem to use default Windows networking.  For example, `Internet Explorer` hangs somewhat and sometimes will start working after a long while of waiting.  It simply won't load websites readily while `Firefox` loads up sites just fine.  `TeamViewer` likewise will not immediately connect to the Internet and will only negotiate a connection after one or two retries.

I also have attempted to run `Autopatcher` and it will hang on updates at the 2nd update at the very end of the update and will progress no further and therefore requires a restart of the system.

I have run `Malwarebytes Anti-Malware`, `AVG`, `AdwCleaner`, `RogueKiller`, `ESET`, `tdsskiller`, `sfc /scannow` with `SFCFix` and found no errors, and even [`Windows Repair`](http://www.tweaking.com/content/page/windows_repair_all_in_one.html).  I have also reset the networking stack via `netsh int ip reset` and still have this issue.

Of course I also do not see any issues in `ipconfig /all` and name resolution is working fine via `cmd`.  The Windows networking troubleshooter finds no apparent issues either and no proxy is configured.

Any thoughts on what may be causing this particular issue with the networking?

**Update:** 
It appears that [someone else has had perhaps the same issue](http://cl.ly/410D2c2U1n2s) as well recently.

Comment: capture a dump of the hanging Explorer Window (run processexplorer, use the crosshair to find the explore.exe. If you found it, make a rightclick on it in ProcExp and create a full dump). Now Run DiagDiag Analyzer (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42933) and select "Crash/**Hang** Analysis and add your dump with "Add data files" and click on Start. After this is done, look if it can detect any issues.

Comment: @magicandre1981 unfortunately I am getting simply some information that a network connection is being created by WinInet Library with no real additional information from the dump analysis.

Comment: Please post the complete report (onedrive) and insert a link here.

Comment: Here are two samples from Explorer (when I used Process Explorer's target function on Network and Sharing Center, it gave me Explorer): 1) http://cl.ly/2R2p451Z3x1o & 2) http://cl.ly/050F0b1g1r3g - I also had a hang on IE and so I'm attaching that for good measure: http://cl.ly/1m1K0P0R012g

Comment: @magicandre1981 did you not see those uploads I provided for you?

Comment: yes, I saw them. Windows hangs during Network status detection. How do you connect to the Internet? Wifi? Dial- Up?

Comment: Have tried both wifi and ethernet @magicandre1981.

Comment: do you have any issues in "safe mode with networking"?

Comment: The same problem exists in safe mode with networking @magicandre1981.

Comment: I have no real idea how to fix this, because I never saw it before.

Comment: @magicandre1981check this out: http://cl.ly/410D2c2U1n2s